# Multiple SSL based IPs on lighttpd

Tags: web-server, ssl-certificate, lighttpd

I have lighttpd as web server and on it I have installed IP-based SSL certificates.

I want to have a way to have multiple SSL certificates on each new IP that the server may get.

For example, at the moment I have `https://127.0.0.1` and it works, but it certificate on which the CN = `127.0.0.1`, so if the webserver gets a new IP from the DHCP server, say `192.168.1.x`, the server will cause SSL mismatches.

Instead I need a new certificate exclusively for that IP address.

How can I create a multi-IP based SSL certificate? Of course on lighttpd.

Comment: Why is your server getting it's IP using DHCP?

Comment: I putted in this way , the servers are actually routers :) so that's why i said it was with dhcp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correct, but if you want to serve the same certificate on all IP interfaces on the server, define a socket without giving an IP:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
     ssl.engine                  = "enable" 
     ssl.pemfile                 = "/path/to/ssl/certificate.pem" 
}
```

This way it listens and serves https with the same certificate (`certificate.pem`) on all interfaces, no matter what IP address has been assigned

Comment: It seems you understood it correctly , ok that looks good , now i have to find out a  method to generate a certificate that will run on all ip addresses

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

3 options:

- Use different certificates by listening on each ip with a separate `$SERVER["socket"]` block
- Use [TLS/SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) ("Server Name Indication") - not supported by all clients
- Use SubjectAltName, see http://wiki.cacert.org/VhostTaskForce (I recommend going for this option)